# How to get the directory path in a string variable having the given directory name in Asp.Net core API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am  trying to get the full  path name of the folder 'Images' in API controller. But the following syntax is not working. If Someone can help, it would be very appreciated

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need System.Web or HttpContext. You can read the web app's root path from [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_WebRootPath).WebRootPath in ASP.NET Core 2.x, or [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostEnvironment_WebRootPath).WebPath in ASP.NET Core 3.x.

The dependency injection mechanism knows about that interface which means you can add it as a dependency to your controllers or services, eg :

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public MyController(IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {

        var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Images");
        ...
    }
```

You can pass the root path to your class's constructor. After all, a class named ImagesFilesRepository only cares about its local folder, not whether it's hosted on a web or console application. For that to work, the methods should not be static:

```
public class ImagesFilesRepository 
{

    public ImagesFilesRepository (string rootPath)
    {
        _rootPath=rootPath;
    }

    public DriveService GetService()
    {
         //Operations.... 

    public List<GoogleDriveFiles> GetDriveFiles()
    {
        // Other operations....
    }

}
```

You can register that class as a service in Startup.cs :

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSignleton<GoogleDriveFilesRepository>(_ =>{
            var gdriveRoot=Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath,"GoogleDriveFiles");
            return new GoogleDriveFilesRepository(gdrivePath);
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

This class can now be used as a dependency on a controller. It's no longer necessary to use IWebHostEnvironment in the controller :

```
public class MyController : Controller 

{
    private ImagesFilesRepository _gdrive;

    public MyController(ImagesFilesRepository gdrive) {
        _gdrive=gdrive;
    }
}
```